# How can I determine if the selected node is a child or parent node in TreeView?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, treeview, treenode

How can I find out if the selected node is a child node or a parent node in the `TreeView` control?

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Exactly how you implement such a check depends on how you define "child" and "parent" nodes. But there are two properties exposed by each `TreeNode` object that provide important information:

1. The [`Nodes` property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.treenode.nodes.aspx) returns the collection of `TreeNode` objects contained by that particular node. So, by simply checking to see how many child nodes the selected node contains, you can determine whether or not it is a parent node:

   ```
   if (selectedNode.Nodes.Count == 0)
   {
       MessageBox.Show("The node does not have any children.");
   }
   else
   {
       MessageBox.Show("The node has children, so it must be a parent.");
   }
   ```
2. To obtain more information, you can also examine the value of the `Parent` property. If this value is `null`, then the node is at the root level of the `TreeView` (it does not have a parent):

   ```
   if (selectedNode.Parent == null)
   {
       MessageBox.Show("The node does not have a parent.");
   }
   else
   {
       MessageBox.Show("The node has a parent, so it must be a child.");
   }
   ```

Answer (score 7):

You can use the [**`TreeNode.Parent`**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.treenode.parent.aspx) property for this.

If its value is a `null`-reference,  the node is at the root level.

```
TreeView treeView = ...
var selectedNode = treeView.SelectedNode;

if(selectedNode ! = null)
{
    if(selectedNode.Parent == null)  
    {     
        // Root-level node  
    }
    else 
    {     
        // Child node
    } 
}
else
{
    // A node hasn't been selected.
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
private void treeView1_AfterSelect(object sender, TreeViewEventArgs e)
{  
   Label1.Text = "";
   if(e.Node.Parent!= null && 
     e.Node.Parent.GetType() == typeof(TreeNode) )
   {
      Label1.Text = "Parent: " + e.Node.Parent.Text + "\n"
         + "Index Position: " + e.Node.Parent.Index.ToString();
   }
   else
   {
      Label1.Text = "This is parent node.";
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For root node is the parent TreeView .. it is possible to check if we compare the types of ->

```
if (currentNode.Parent.GetType() == typeof(TreeView)) 
{
    // root node
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
treeview.SelectedNode == null
```

is the best to choose.

Comment: I don't understand how this answers the question.