# Adding child to an existing treenode

Tags: c#, .net

I want to check if a treenode is exists and if exists then add child to that existing TreeNode.

Suppose I have a TreeNode treeroot and a child treechild1. I have created treenode like this:

```
TreeNode[] tchild = new TreeNode[] {"childe1"};

TreeNode troot = new TreeNode("treeroot",tchild);
```

Now I want to check if the treeroot is created or not. If created then i want to add another child to that node which i get after checking. How can I do this?

Comment: Does `TreeNode` have other methods?

Comment: No. I want to check if a node is already created or not?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I determine if the selected node is a child or parent node in TreeView?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5684781/how-can-i-determine-if-the-selected-node-is-a-child-or-parent-node-in-treeview)

Comment: `new TreeNode[] {"childe1"}` implies `string` is implicitly castable from `TreeNode`. What are we working with? Windows Forms `TreeNodes`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You may try `Nodes.Find("key",bool searchAllChildren)` method. To use this method you have to add key-value [tree node](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/57aa8e09.aspx).

For instance,

```
//Add First node
TreeView1.Nodes.Add("Root","Root");
```

and define a method that search and add a node,

```
public void SearchAndAdd(string searchKey, string newValue)
 {
  TreeNode[] list = treeView1.Nodes.Find(searchKey, true);
  if (list.Length != 0)
   {
    list[0].Nodes.Add(newValue,newValue);
   }
 }
```

Call `SearchAndAdd` method to add a node at given key,

```
SearchAndAdd("Root","First");  //added under Root
SearchAndAdd("Root","Second"); // do
SearchAndAdd("Second","2");    // added at Second
```